# How to make XPages application layout left column collapsible/resizable?

Tags: javascript, xpages

My app uses: Application theme: OneUI V2.1.
I want to make left column of application layout collapsible or resizable.
Or even possibility to hide/show it by CSJS or SSJS.
The layout configuration options don't really work

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the xe:bootstrapResponsiveConfiguration as configuration for your ApplicationLayout. That does not combine well with the OneUI theme.
Theme and ApplicationLayout must be of the same family.

So either use a bootstrap theme or use the oneuiApplication layout (but the latter does not have a collapsible left column)